# Paracompactness of Adjunction Spaces

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, paracompactness

In this question I will understand the definition of paracompactness to include the Hausdorff separation axiom.

Let $X$ be a paracompact space and $A\subseteq X$ a closed subspace. Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a continuous map to a paracompact space $B$ and form the adjunction space $B\cup_fX$ as the pushout in the next square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    A@> \subseteq >>  X\\
    @VfV V   @VV  V\\
    B @>>> B\cup_fX.
\end{CD}
I believe it is true that $B\cup_fX$ is paracompact under the assumptions above. The proof of this that I have seen used Michael's Selection Theorem.

> Is there a more direct way to prove that $B\cup_fX$ is paracompact? Say using only the machinery developed in Munkres's text book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this classic [paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1957-008-04/S0002-9939-1957-0087079-9/S0002-9939-1957-0087079-9.pdf) E.Michael showed that the closed and continuous image of a paracompact space is again paracompact. He does this via a characterisation of paracompactness that stays pretty close to how Munkres treats paracompactness, so it should be pretty accessible to you.

And in your set-up, the (quotient) map from the sum of $B$ and $X$ (which is paracompact) to $B\cup_f X$ is closed (as $A$ is closed in $X$).